# Extract all HTML tags, including closing tags, from file using Java without using external library like Jsoup

Tags: java, html, regex, file-io

I have this code that will take in a HTML file, get all the opening HTML tags, and then print them. I was wondering if there was a way to also include the closing tags within this code. So right now it prints:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
<body>
<table>
<p>
<a>
<p>
etc. etc.
```

I'm looking for it to print with the closing tags as well.

```
<p>
<a>
</a>
</p>
```

Here's the code I have thus far:

```
        try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.html"));
        String line;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
        }
        String pageContent = stringBuilder.toString();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<(?!!)(?!/)\\s*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(.*?)>");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(pageContent);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String tagName = matcher.group(1);
            System.out.println("<" + tagName + ">");
        }
        in.close();
    }
```

Edit: Is there a way to do it without using an external library like Jsoup?
Edit 2: I changed my Pattern.compile to this-> <([a-zA-Z0-9]+|/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(.*?)> and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: sounds like a job for jsoup

Comment: You can't catch every valid case by trying to [parse html using regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/17300)

Answer (score 1):

If its fine to use external library you can go with JSoup as described here. [Extract Tags from a html file using Jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929112/extract-tags-from-a-html-file-using-jsoup)

Comment: I know about the external libraries. Is there a way to do it without one?

Comment: Here are some pointers doing the same with regex.
http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/all_about_html_tags.htm
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847333/extract-all-html-tag-closed-with-a-regex-expresion

Can I know the reason you don't want to go with JSoup and take all the pain to parse the HTML on your own ?

Comment: I prefer you to check this post before taking approach of regex parsing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags